# How to get meta-data from rrd file?

Tags: rrdtool

My monitoring system (check_mk) is missing lots of RRD files. While it appears I can resolve the issue by replacing a missing file with one for the corresponding service from another host, this would also copy over the data from that host.

Is it possible to get the meta-data required for creating an RRD file from the file so I can then create a new empty one?

(asking Google, I got bombarded with results on how to get data, not meta-data, from an rrd file).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the rrdtool info command to extract metadata from an existing RRD file without retrieving the actual data

```
rrdtool info your_existing_file.rrd > metadata.txt
```

But don't you have a backup to restore those files?

Comment: Yes, info describes the structure of the rrd file, but not in a way which obviously  translates to the syntax of `rrdtool create` (in the case of my monitoring system, the specific command is generated at runtime, so I can't simply copy it from the source code). For now it looks like re-writeing the output of `dump` to remove existing data then using `restore` might be more achievable.